# What are these white bits in my mesh?

Tags: mesh

In wireframe mode i can see these white bits in my mesh
[image]

And in solid mode the mesh is not in line with the edges and vertices

[image]

How does this happen and how do i fix it?

Comment: Looks like an internal face. Often the practical way to find and delete it is to  come out of X-ray mode to a solid view, and progressively H hide faces you know to be good, until the bad stuff appears. Delete, and Alt-H to make the rest visible again.

Answer (score 2):

I've done my best to recreate your issue, I think you've created several n-gons here, and the artifact you're seeing is Blender triangulating that n-gon.

[image]

You can create better topology in a somewhat automatic fashion by using a bevel on this corner.  I'll be starting over with a primitive cube, and I've just scaled up the bottom to create this tapered shape of yours.

Just select one edge and bevel it with the desired number of segments.

[image]

And then select the top corner's vertices and do a Merge At Center.

[image]

[image]

This has created a triangle for each segment of the corner.  Note that typically it is recommended to stick to 4-sided faces called quads, but the most important thing is to avoid n-gons unless you are looking for some very particular behavior.

Comment: How did you add more vertices to the top vertice? doesnt seem to work with bevel for me. I only have one edge connecting the top vertice to the bottom ones

Comment: I started with a new cube, chose one of the side edges, which will select both vertices on the edge, and used the bevel tool.  You can scroll wheel up and down to change the number of segments, or once you've completed the operation you can expand the box that appears in the bottom left to modify your last action and add more segments or adjust the bevel amount.